# Stuck on a SQL Query (Distinct?)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm making a webpage for a library and I need to make a list that shows all the books which are not rented within the past year.

At the moment I have a Query that filters on the Rent table, where all the records are of rented books. But can be rented multiple times so a book can show up multiple times in the table. The problem is, when a book isn't rented to a person for more then a year, but the same book is rented to another person within the past year, it shows still that book because it saw one record fullfilling the conditions. But I need to know which book isn't rented at all in the past year. Can anyone help me with that?

I changed the real query to an easier to understand query (language difference), so don't check on bad spelling or simple syntax problems.

My query a.t.m.:

```
SELECT
  Book.BookID,
  Book.BoekTitle, 
  Writer.WriterName 
FROM (
    (Book INNER JOIN BookWriter ON Book.BookID=BookWriter.BookID) 
    INNER JOIN Writer ON BookWriter.WriterID=Writer.WriterID
  )
  INNER JOIN BookRenting ON Book.BookID=BookRenting.BookID
WHERE
  BookRenting.RentDate < DATEADD('yyyy', -1, NOW());
```

I use an MS Access database!

Thanks in advance for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you probably need to take care of the condition where the book has *never* been rented.  This requires an outer join.

This should get you what you want:

```
select b.BookID, b.BookTitle, w.WriterName
from book b left outer join
     (select BookId, max(RentDate) as MaxRentDate
      from BookRenting br
      group by BookId
     ) br
     on b.BookId = br.BookId left outer join
     BookWriter bw
     on b.BookId = bw.BookId left outer join
     Writer w
     on bw.WriterId = w.WriterId
where br.MaxRentDate < DATEADD('yyyy', -1, NOW());
```

And, I meant to add that books can have multiple writers.  You will still get duplicates in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I think this boils down to structuring your query in a better way.

Try using `NOT IN <subquery>` instead of doing a join. This makes your query more modular and easier to understand:

```
SELECT Book.*, Writer.*
FROM
Book 
INNER JOIN BookWriter ON Book.BookID=BookWriter.BookID
INNER JOIN Writer ON BookWriter.WriterID=Writer.WriterID
WHERE
Book.BookID NOT IN (
    SELECT BookRenting.BookID
    FROM BookRenting 
    WHERE BookRenting.RentDate >= DATEADD('yyyy', -1, NOW())
);
```

I don't have Access so I haven't tested this though

Comment: this is wrong, this will return all books with rendate in last one year, he wants list that is not rented in last year

Comment: No, this technique works. I don't have Access, but I tested it with SQLServer and it worked fine.  You must do any syntax fixes for Access though. Idea is that the subquery gets all rentals during the last year. Then we pick the books that are NOT IN that list. That leaves us with the unpopular books nobody wanted to rent during the last year, which I understood was what the OP was after.

Comment: check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a7a94/2 for your query, subquery is returning all rows before one year and not during last year, he is subtracting -1 from year, your query will be valid if subquery was checking `BookRenting.RentDate >= DATEADD('yyyy', -1, NOW()`

Comment: My bad, now I've flipped the comparison operator and I think the query should just about do it.

Answer (score -1):

It appears you're missing `<sometablehere> INNER JOIN Writer ON BookWriter.WriterID=Writer.WriterID`

So it might look like:

```
SELECT
  Book.BookID,
  Book.BoekTitle, 
  Writer.WriterName 
FROM (
    (Book INNER JOIN BookWriter ON Book.BookID=BookWriter.BookID) 
    **CODETALKSTABLE** INNER JOIN Writer ON BookWriter.WriterID=Writer.WriterID
  )
  INNER JOIN BookRenting ON Book.BookID=BookRenting.BookID
WHERE
  BookRenting.RentDate < DATEADD('yyyy', -1, NOW());
```